# Sprite Kit - Apply static impulse

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, gravity

I have a simple example where I'm applying an impulse to a node on touch like so :

```
[_bird.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 15)];
```

What I want is to apply a "static" impulse.

Let me explain :
When my node is in a falling phase, due to gravity, applying an impulse will be harder and the impulse will apply a `dy` of 5 instead of 15 (for example).

In another case, when my node is not falling (i.e is on the ground), if I tapped multiple time quickly, my impulse seems to be multiplied and not being added, causing my node to reach the "roof" way too fast.

I want to apply the same number of `dy`, whenever the case.

Is there anyway to do that ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to make the impulse have the same effect on the sprite node regardless of it's state, you could try setting it's `velocity` property to zero. Like so:

```
_bird.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0,0);
[_bird.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 15)];
```

This should make the 'bird' (Flappy Bird?) behave the same way in the any situation.

Comment: ohhh my god _bird.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0,0); was the thing that I was looking for so long, thx man

Comment: Yes its work with static impulse but not move left and right

Comment: @JugalKBalara what do you mean? You want the impulse to make it move left/right? Then you should provide a value for the x variable as well. Eg.  `[_bird.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(15, 15)];` You could also post a new question with this.

Comment: Thanks @ZeMoom
[_bird.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(15, 15)]; this line code work but always move right